# divide list into vectors

Tags: r, list, vector

I have this `list`:

```
list <- list(a=1, b=1:3, c=4)
```

if I unlist it returns the following:

```
> unlist(list)
 a b1 b2 b3  c 
 1  1  2  3  4
```

is there a way to pull the `list` apart so I can get:

```
a <- 1
b <- 1:3
c <- 4
```

thanks

Comment: name it something *not* "list" and `list2env(l, envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: I suspect this is a bad thing to do. The objects are in a list for a reason right? They should stay together. There's no efficiency in pulling them apart into separate a list and create named variables this way, plus there's a chance you'll stomp on existing variables without noticing. Debug hell. But hey, can't say you've not been warned!

Comment: totally right...I have re-written this part to avoid the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following rawr's advice, avoid naming objects like "list", "dataframe", etc

A non-optimal solution using a `for-loop` where `data` is your list:

```
for (i in 1:length(data)) {
assign (names(data)[i],data[[i]])
}
```

Checking the objects created:

```
> ls()
 "a"    "b"    "c"    "data" "i"  
> a
[1] 1
> b
[1] 1 2 3
> c
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, this is not advisable. Breaking these variables out of their list environment just creates more variables in the global environment that we have to keep track of.

But if you must, you could do something like this, with `assign()` and `mapply()`:

```
> ls()
# character(0)
> X <- list(a = 1, b = 1:3, d = 4)
> invisible(mapply(function(x, y) assign(x, y, .GlobalEnv), names(X), X))
> ls()
# [1] "a" "b" "d" "X"
```

Or you could evaluate a `call()` to `<-` in a `for` loop:

```
> ls()
# character(0)
> X <- list(a = 1, b = 1:3, d = 4)
> for(i in seq_along(X)){
      eval(call("<-", names(X[i]), X[[i]]))
  }
> ls()
# [1] "a" "b" "d" "i" "X"
```

Note that I am using different variable names to avoid overwriting base R functions `c()` and `list()`

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you want, although its not terribly elegant.

```
count = 0
listNames <- names(listy)
while (count < length(listy)) {
  count = count + 1
  assign(listNames[count], listy[count])
}
```